# Inspecting traffic from a device connected with Connectify

Tags: http, proxy, fiddler

I have a device, which I can't set a proxy on but can connect to WiFi, I need to inspect and modify with Fiddler the traffic of this device. I used my laptop to create a new WiFi connection with Connectify(the first program that does this that I found, Ad-hoc connections are not seen by the device) but fiddler seems to be ignoring the traffic from Connectify. I would like to know if I am missing something or is there any better way to do this. I can see the traffic in Wireshark but it is on a new Network device that Connectify has created, can this influence Fiddler?

Any suggestion / idea would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a proxy, Fiddler only sees traffic that is sent to it. Typically, that means that you set the proxy settings on the device to point at Fiddler. In cases where you can't configure the proxy settings, typically you root the device and use a tool to set the proxy settings. If you control the client application's URL, you can run Fiddler as a [reverse proxy](http://fiddler2.com/r/?reverseproxy) and look at the traffic that way.

Note: If you're only interested in *viewing* (not modifying) the data, and if you have a packet capture, you can import that capture into the latest version of Fiddler using File > Import Sessions.